# How to Save an XML File in Angular2 in the file system

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http, angular2-rc5

I can receive the XML File using HTTP get method and pass it as a Blob.
I can't use the window.open method as it opens the XML file in the web browser.

I know there is a ***FileSaver*** component for AngularJS but it does not work in Angular2.

Please Help

This is my service call.

```html
public downloadXMLFile(): Promise<Blob> {
    return this.http.get('this.downloadURL').toPromise()
      .then((r: Response) => new Blob([r.text()], {type: 'application/xml'}))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: Yeah I have done lots of research on the internet, but did not find a working solution yet. I tried the answers in this question, but did not find the correct way to save a file using typescript.

Answer (score 1):

```
>npm install file-saver --save

>npm install @types/file-saver --save


this.yourService.downloadXML().subscribe(
    response =>{
        const filename = 'filename.xml';
        saveAs(response, filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
>npm install file-saver --save
>npm install @types/file-saver --save


import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
.
.
public downloadXMLFile(): Promise<Blob> {
    return this.http.get('this.downloadURL').toPromise()
      .then((r: Response) => {
          new Blob([r.text()], {type: 'application/xml'});
          saveAs(file, fileName);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Sorry if there are typos.